# Determinant of a positive semi definite matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

Is it possible that the determinant of a positive semi definite matrix is equal to 0. It is coming to be zero in my case. I have a diagonal matrix with diagonal elements non zero. When I try to calculate the determinant of this matrix it is coming out to be 0. Why is it so?

Comment: Are these two separate questions?  One about a positive-definite matrix, and one about a diagonal matrix?  Can you give examples?

Answer (score 8):

This is the reason why computing the determinant is never a good idea. Yeah, I know. Your book, your teacher, or your boss told you to do so. They were probably wrong. Why? Determinants are poorly scaled beasts. Even if you compute the determinant efficiently (many algorithms fail to do even that) you don't really want a determinant most of the time.

Consider this simple positive definite matrix.

```
A = eye(1000);
```

What is the determinant? I need not even bother. It is 1. But, if you insist...

```
det(A)
ans =
     1
```

OK, so that works. How about if we simply multiply that entire matrix by a small constant, 0.1 for example. What is the determinant? You might say there is no reason to bother, as we already know the determinant. It must be just det(A)*0.1^1000, so 1e-1000.

```
det(A*0.1)
ans =
     0
```

What did we do wrong here? Where this failed is we forgot to remember we were working in floating point arithmetic. Since the dynamic range of a double in MATLAB goes down only to essentially

```
realmin
ans =
      2.2250738585072e-308
```

then smaller numbers turn into zero - they underflow. Anyway, most of the time when we compute a determinant, we are doing so for the wrong reasons anyway. If they want you to test to see if a matrix is singular, then use rank or cond, not det.

Answer (score 6):

by definition, a positive semi definite matrix may have eigenvalues equal to zero, so its determinant can therefore be zero

Now, I can't see what you mean with the sentence,

> I have a diagonal matrix with diagonal elements non zero. When I try to calculate the ...

If the matrix is diagonal, and all elements in the diagonal are non-zero, the determinant should be non-zero. If you are calculating it in your computer, beware underflows.
You may consider the sum of logarithms instead of the product of the diagonal elements

Comment: Yes it is a diagonal matrix with diagonal elements equal to nonzero. Still the determinant is equal to 0

Comment: @rajansthapit: Please add an example to your question.